# Identify pattern in text files in a single unix directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

If i want to identify a pattern in Unix in one single directory, may i know which unix utility will be helpful ( like awk )

Input :

$ ls

a_20171007_001.txt
a_20171007_002.txt
b_20171007_001.txt
c_20180101_001.txt

expecting output :

a_20171007_002.txt
b_20171007_001.txt

1. The output should return latest version of file based on filename irrespective of file creation time
2. The output file shouldn't have future dated file ( e.g., current date :20171008 so 20180101 shouldn't come in output )

any suggestions on how to achieve this easily in unix ( awk or sed )

---

Thanks alot for all your solutions. But unfortunately if the file name is not follow any pattern it is not helping.

eg, **input :**

ab_bc_**all**_20171008_001.txt

bc_cd_ad_**all**_20171008_001.txt

ab_bc_**all**_20171008_002.txt

ad_dc_cd_ed_**all**_20180101_001.txt

ae_bc_zx_ed_ac_**all**_20170918_001.txt

**output :**

bc_cd_ad_all_20171008_001.txt

ab_bc_all_20171008_002.txt

ae_bc_zx_ed_ac_all_20170918_001.txt

in above case only pattern after **'all'** the date field is appearing.
Can you please suggest in above case..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you have 4 digits in your version number ? If yes do they start only after 999 ? for eg. `a_20171007_999.txt ` and `a_20171007_1000.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Time::Piece;

my $today = localtime->ymd("");
my %latest;
for my $file (glob '*.txt') {
    my ($id, $date, $num) = split /[_.]/, $file;
    $latest{$id}{$date} = $num
        if $date <= $today
        && (! exists $latest{$id}
            || ! exists $latest{$id}{$date}
            || $num > $latest{$id}{$date});
}
for my $id (keys %latest) {
    for my $date (keys %{ $latest{$id} }) {
        say "$id\_$date\_$latest{$id}{$date}.txt";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple **awk** solution

```
$ awk -F_ -vdate=`date +%Y%m%d` ' !($1 in file) && $2<=date {file[$1]=$0} ($1 in file){if($0>=file[$1]){file[$1]=$0}} END{ for(i in file)print file[i] }' f1
a_20171007_002.txt
b_20171007_001.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Store the current date in `date` variable in the format `yyyymmdd`

While iterating though records/filenames, if the date in filename i.e `$2` is less than or equal to `current date` and the prefix (for eg. a,b etc) doesn't exist in array `file` then store it in `file` array for eg. `file['a']=a_20171007_001.txt` else it won't be stored and in this example `c_20180101_001.txt` would be straight forwardly rejected.

For next records, if the `prefix` i.e `$1` exists in array `file` then check if the whole record is greater than the existing record (lexicographically). If yes, overwrite the record in `file` array.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
ls -ltr *.txt | awk -v date=$(date +%Y) -F"_" 'prev != $1 && val && date_val<=date{print val} {prev=$1;val=$0;date_val=substr($2,1,4)} END{if(date_val<=date){print val}}'
```

Adding a better readable form of solution too now.

```
ls -ltr *.txt |  awk -v date=$(date +%Y) -F"_" '
prev != $1 && val && date_val<=date{
  print val
}
{
prev=$1;
val=$0
date_val=substr($2,1,4)
}
END{
if(date_val<=date){
 print val
}
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **Awk** solution for static filename format `<prefix>_<date>_<version>.txt`:

Exemplary `ls -1` output (extended):

```
a_20171007_001.txt
a_20171007_002.txt
b_20171007_001.txt
c_20180101_001.txt
a_20171007_0010.txt
b_20171007_004.txt
```

---

```
ls -1 | awk -F'[_.]' '{ k=$1"_"$2 }{ if (a[k]<$3) a[k]=$3 }
        END{ 
            for (i in a) { 
                split(substr(i, index(i,"_")+1), b, "");
                ts=mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 00 00 00",b[1]b[2]b[3]b[4],b[5]b[6],b[7]b[8]));
                if (systime() >= ts) print i"_"a[i]".txt" 
            } 
        }'
```

The output:

```
b_20171007_004.txt
a_20171007_0010.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is ok only in shell (dash)

```
d=$(date +%Y%m%d)
ls -1r *_*_*.txt|while IFS='_' read w x y
do
 [ "$x" -le "$d" ] && [ "$v" != "$w$x" ] && { echo "$w"_"$x"_"$y";v="$w$x";}
done
```

The spec change ???
Try this one

```
d=$(date +%Y%m%d)
ls -1r *_*_*.txt|while read l
do
 b="${l%_*_*}"
 a="${l#$b*_}"
 c="${a%_*}"
 [ "$c" -le "$d" ] && [ "$v" != "$b$c" ] && { echo "$l";v="$b$c";}
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ ls -1r | awk -v today="$(date +%Y%m%d)" -F'_' '($2 <= today) && !seen[$1,$2]++'
b_20171007_001.txt
a_20171007_002.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the issue instead of just posting some code? This will be far more helpful, especially for beginners, thanks.

Comment: No it's completely clear, obvious and brief so anyone who doesn't understand it would benefit far more from from glancing at the man pages. I assume you asked for an explanation to this brief, trivial answer but not the lengthier more complicated ones on this page because a tool flagged it as **possibly** low quality given how brief it is. If you don't know the domain then don't comment, just move on.

Comment: Compact code is good and helps. But explanation is essential, you can also link or quote some of the man pages. Or give a very brief explanation on what the commands do. It's your decision, but this will improve the quality of the answer and of course prevent low-quality flags.